# .className() seem doesnt Work

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom

I Have a table with rows added dynamically. These rows contain a date picker and dropdown, I am able to set classname on the  but not on the datepicker and dropdown using .className()

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
row.className = "row1 part";

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.className = "value";
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "text";
element1.name = "txtbox[]";
element1.className = "date-pick"; // this fails
element1.setAttribute('value', '2013/10/04');
cell1.appendChild(element1);

var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var element2 = document.createElement("select");
element2.name = "prddrop[]";
element2.id = "prddrop[]";
element2.className = "bankopt"; //this also fails
element2.options[element2.length] = new Option("[-- Please Choose --]", "[-- Please Choose --]");
var arr_items = [{
    "IssuingBank": " --- "
}, {
    "IssuingBank": " --- "
}];
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_items.length; i++) {
        element2.options[element2.length] = new Option(arr_items[i].IssuingBank, arr_items[i].IssuingBank);
    }
});
cell2.appendChild(element2);
```

Please help me with this... Thanks!

Comment: So what's wrong? Setting the `className` property worked for me.

Comment: className() is not a method

Comment: working fine here.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTcUM/).. are there any errors in console?

Comment: in the rest of the code, it is supposed to display a date picker when the class is identified, i didnt pot it because the code is quite long... Anyway, thanks for wring the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `.appendChild()` returns the element.

So you could do:

```
cell1.appendChild(element1).className = "class_to_add";
```

Another way:

You can use `setAttribute` (NOTE: This will **not work** on IE8 and earlier versions as stated by @om in the comments.)

```
var i = document.createElement('input'); 
i.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
document.forms[0].appendChild(i);
```

Comment: I was able to assign `className` on an element not in the DOM. Is this browser specific?

Comment: Well that's IE7, it's a special case. Hardly the benchmark to make statements like "You can't do it."

Comment: I want to give a method that works in all browsers including IE6+

Comment: @Umpong_1947676 : Let me know if any of the above work for you. All should.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta `className` works for me in IE6+, the property `className` is named such to prevent situations where the `class` property and keyword might become confused. There is nothing to suggest `className` would ever not perform it's duty as a DOM element on the page is functionally the same as one not present not present on the page minus the availability of properties that depend on the element being rendered.

Comment: @izuriel: removed that method.

Comment: this isn't a cross browser solution

Comment: Which one of these is not crossbrowser?

Comment: setAttribute is not supported in IE8 and earlier

Comment: welcome! in addition to the one's that you provided, see my answer below for a cross browser solution

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Across all browsers.

```
var yourClass = document.createAttribute("class");
yourClass.value = "date-pick";
element1.setAttributeNode(yourClass);
```